# Will there be secret hats in this season?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2016

Has anyone already found a secret hat this year?

Comment: Related: [Winter Bash 2016 - All Hats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288271/294055)

Comment: There are no secret hats and even if there were nobody would be allowed to tell you and even if they did tell you, you wouldn't be allowed to know and even if you somehow found out about the glorious, amazing secret hats that everyone has, you still wouldn't be allowed to talk about it. Sssh!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [announcement blog](http://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/Its-Hat-Season-Announcing-Winter-Bash-2016/?cb=1):

> We've got some secret hats lined up

So there will be secret hats, and [some of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288284/295232) have already been discovered.